# Trying to apply CSS text decoration after input checkbox is checked

Tags: html, css, html-table, checked

I am having issue trying to apply a CSS style to a sibling element after an input of checkbox has been checked.  My goal is to apply the text-decoration of line-through and text-decoraction-color red to the sibling element.

DEMO: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/uteezy/y57gerta/)

```css
    input:checked + td.p1Amount {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm table-responsive">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th scope="col">Item</th>
           <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
           <th scope="col">Paid</th>
           <th scope="col">Amount</th>
           <th scope="col">Notes</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <th scope="row">Utility</th>
           <td>05/15/2020</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
           <td class="p1Amount">$1.00</td>
           <td>Confirmation #5477ff59de</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
```

Am I not using the right CSS selector to select the sibling after the checkbox has been checked?

Comment: your input is inside a td.  so input has no siblings.  I believe you will need to use jquery or js

Comment: @DCR Thank you for your input.  I totally missed that!  I will either write a js for that or add a span within the same cell to make it a sibling element in order to apply the css style upon checked status.

Answer (score 0):

**you can do it by vanilla js**

```js
document.querySelector(".checkbox").onchange = function(){
  var check = document.querySelector("input").checked;
  if(check == true){
   document.querySelector(".p1Amount").style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    document.querySelector(".p1Amount").style.textDecorationColor = "red";
   }else {
 document.querySelector(".p1Amount").style.textDecoration = null;
  document.querySelector(".p1Amount").style.textDecorationColor = null;
 }
 } ;
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm table-responsive">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th scope="col">Item</th>
           <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
           <th scope="col">Paid</th>
           <th scope="col">Amount</th>
           <th scope="col">Notes</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <th scope="row">Utility</th>
           <td>05/15/2020</td>
           <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
           <td class="p1Amount">$1.00</td>
           <td>Confirmation #5477ff59de</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion for using the js above.  I might use this if I have trouble using the CSS selector.  I plan on just moving the content into the same <td> as the input and tagging it with the span element.  If it doesn't work as plan.  I will apply the js instead.

Comment: Hi Abdullah.  Yes my problem has been sovled.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I used `JQuery`. **Please Try this...**

```js
(function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".check").click(function(){
            if($(".check").prop('checked')){
               $(".p1Amount").css("text-decoration","line-through");
               $(".p1Amount").css("text-decoration-color","red");
            }else{
               $(".p1Amount").css("text-decoration","");
               $(".p1Amount").css("text-decoration-color","");
            }
        });
        
    });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm table-responsive">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th scope="col">Item</th>
           <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
           <th scope="col">Paid</th>
           <th scope="col">Amount</th>
           <th scope="col">Notes</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <th scope="row">Utility</th>
           <td>05/15/2020</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" class="check"></td>
           <td class="p1Amount">$1.00</td>
           <td>Confirmation #5477ff59de</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
```

Comment: Rayees,  Thank you helping me with the jQuery version.  Really appreciate it!